# How to get previous ArrayList value?

Tags: java, arraylist, bit

Here is an arraylist of items:

item 1: (weight:4, profit:5)
item 2: (weight:10, profit:12)
item 3: (weight:5, profit:8)

and capacity = 11 and random bit to be flipped (if 0 will become 1 and vice versa):
orderList = [2,0,1].

my code:

'

```
public class BitString {
   public static void main (String[] args){
    int n = 3, capacity = 11, pointer, toFlip;

    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentSolution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> flipOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> improve = new   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    itemList.add(new Item(4,5));
    itemList.add(new Item(10,12));
    itemList.add(new Item(5,8));

    solution = initialSolution(n);
    currentSolution = solution;
    flipOrder = randomFlipOrder(n);

    System.out.println("List of Items: " + itemList);
    System.out.println("Initial solution: " + solution);
    System.out.println("Current solution: " + currentSolution);
    System.out.println("Random order: " + flipOrder);

    for (int i = 0; i < flipOrder.size(); i++){
        int totalWeight = 0, totalProfit = 0;

        pointer = flipOrder.get(i);
        toFlip = solution.get(pointer);

        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < solution.size(); j++){
            if (solution.get(j) == 1){
                totalWeight += itemList.get(j).getWeight();
                totalProfit += itemList.get(j).getProfit();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total Weight For Solution " + solution + " : " + totalWeight + " | Total Profit For Solution " + solution + " : " + totalProfit);

        if (totalWeight <= capacity){
            System.out.println(totalWeight + " NOT EXCEED CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: " + solution);
            currentSolution = solution;
            improve.add(currentSolution);
            System.out.println("Updated Current Solution: " + solution);
            System.out.println("Updated Improved: " + improve);

            //do the flipping bits
            if (toFlip == 1)
                solution.set(pointer, 0);
            else
                solution.set(pointer, 1);

            System.out.println("New Solution After flip: " + solution);
            //improve.remove(0);
        }
        else{
             System.out.println(totalWeight + " EXCEEDS CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: " + solution);
            //solution = currentSolution;
            System.out.println("SOLUTION REVERTED: " + improve.get(0));

            //do the flipping bits

            if (toFlip == 1)
                 solution.set(pointer, 0);
            else
                solution.set(pointer, 1);

            System.out.println("New Solution After flip: " + solution);
        }

    }

}

//generate initial solution(bits) randomly
public static ArrayList<Integer> initialSolution(int length){
     Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>(length);

    // generate some random boolean values
    boolean[] booleans = new boolean[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++) {
      booleans[i] = r.nextBoolean();
    }

    for (boolean b : booleans) {
      if (b == true){
          solution.add(1);
      }
      else{
          solution.add(0);
       }
    }

    return solution;

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> randomFlipOrder(int length){
     ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     Random r = new Random();

     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        order.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(order);

    return order;
   }
  }
```

'

have generate random bit string.
Eg: **[0,1,0]** means Item 2 is taken and give total weight = 10.

So if total weight <= capacity then keep the **[0,1,0]** at an arraylist.

Then, I need to flip the bit at index 2 (based on the orderList):
Eg: **[0,1,1]** means Item 2 & 3 are taken and give total weight = 15.

I would like to take back the previous value stored **[0,1,0]** and work from previous value:
[0,1,0] => next bit to be flip is at index 0 and bcomes **[1,1,0]** instead of taking the latest (exceeded capacity) [0,1,1] and flip it  [1,1,1].

But I keep getting the updated value and unable to get the previous value whenever capacity is exceeded.

My output: 
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3GNK.png)

Comment: You should really ask the question *in the body of the question*, not just in the title... and please reduce your question to a [mcve]. It's fairly unclear what you're asking at the moment, but if you want to know the old value, call `get()` before you call `set()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get previous ArrayList value after .set() is used?

You can't unless you have a backup copy of your list using `new ArrayList<Integer>(myListToBackup)`

Comment: You create the backup before doing a flip, then if you want to revert it, you take this backup